# Ordering a query result by another query result (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sorting

Table structure:

folders:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| Field        | Type         |
+--------------+--------------+
| id           | int(11)      |
| project_id   | int(11)      |
| finished     | int(11)      |
| approved     | int(11)      |
| comment      | varchar(500) |
+--------------+--------------+
```

werte:

```
+---------------------+---------------+
| Field               | Type          |
+---------------------+---------------+
| id                  | int(11)       |
| folder_id           | int(11)       |
| form_id             | int(11)       |
| werte               | varchar(5000) |
| number              | int(11)       |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

Now I have a situation where I want to retrieve the id field from folders in a certain order. The first couple of sortings I need are easy to achieve, since the order is determined by fields in the table. For example

```
SELECT id FROM folders ORDER BY approved ASC;
```

To make it a bit less abstract, the werte table holds parameter values, like dates in this example. Folders can contain multiple forms, which in turn contain multiple werte.

My problem is: I want to get all ids from the folders table, ordered by the newest date of each id stored in werte (each id will in most cases hold more than one relevant werte record).

A valid query to get the newest date from a certain folder would be

```
SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(werte, '%d.%m.%Y')) FROM werte WHERE number = 2 AND folder_id = 42;
```

How would I go about sorting the first query by the result of this second query?

---

EDIT:

The problem in the other question was a different one. The solution,

```
SELECT f.id FROM folders f JOIN werte w ON w.folder_id = f.id WHERE w.number = 2 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(werte, '%d.%m.%Y');
```

will yield ALL dates in the table. However, I only want ONE result (the newest one) from each respective id. Each folder will have multiple *werte* entries that hold a date, I only want the ids sorted by each respective maximum date though. For perspective, the above query yields about 8000 results, however there are only about 1900 distinctive IDs in the table.

Comment: This is the same table I am talking about, the problem is a different one, however. If I try to apply the solution given in the other question I asked (SELECT f.id FROM folders f JOIN werte w ON w.folder_id = f.id WHERE w.number = 2 ORDER BY MAX(STR_TO_DATE(werte, '%d.%m.%Y'));), I only get a single result (the ID with the newest date). However I want to get all ids, sorted by their respective newest date.

Comment: See aggregate functions and the GROUP BY clause